Why can't enable pcie netcard?
The OS in my pc:
uname  -a
Linux MiWiFi-R4A-srv 6.1.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux

My PCIE card:

The home net structure is simple: wifi router,ip address is 192.31.242,list pcie card:
lspci -k | grep  net -A 2
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
    Kernel modules: r8168

To show complete information about known devices:
nmcli  device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         0A:E0:AF:C7:09:AD
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected (externally))
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     enp4s0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveC>
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.31.242/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.31.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.31.1, mt >
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.31.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt>
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 192.168.31.1/32, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt>
IP4.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt >
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::8e0:afff:fec7:9ad/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected (externally))
lines 1-23...skipping...
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         0A:E0:AF:C7:09:AD
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected (externally))
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     enp4s0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.31.242/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.31.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.31.1, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.31.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 192.168.31.1/32, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::8e0:afff:fec7:9ad/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected (externally))
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     lo
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:E0:72:64:2C:19
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --

I want to list all wifi with the pcie card:
sudo nmcli device  wifi  list

Why got nothing with above command?
connmanctl technologies
/net/connman/technology/ethernet
  Name = Wired
  Type = ethernet
  Powered = True
  Connected = True
  Tethering = False
  TetheringFreq = 2412

Show wireless extensions:
sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

Enable wifi:
connmanctl enable wifi
wifi is not available

Does it mean that my pcie netcard can't work?
sudo  ethtool -i enp4s0
Cannot get driver information: No such device
lspci -knn -d ::0280


Possibly missing drivers, as nmcli is not detecting any WiFi interfaces. What distribution are you running? please edit your question to include this.

Some WiFi devices use USB, even internal ones. It works like PCIe -> USB -> WiFi. But usually this is only used for Bluetooth functionality,

Your PCIe card 04:00.0 is the wired network interface enp4s0. If you don't believe it, run ethtool -i enp4s0 and see what it tells you. Run lspci -knn -d ::0280 to see if your system has any wireless PCI network interfaces accessible on the PCIe lanes. If not, you might need a driver to a particular PCIe bridge chip that is currently hiding the wireless interfaces.

Which driver should i install?
